# update MongoDB document sub object without replacing

Tags: mongodb, gamesparks

So I have this document in my database like below

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59a8668f900bea0528b63fdc"
  },
  "userId": "KingSlizzard",
  "credits": 15,
  "settings": {
    "music": 1,
    "sfx": 0
  }
}
```

I have this method for updating just specific fields in a document

```
function setPlayerDataField(targetUserId, updateObject) {
    playerDataCollection.update({
            "userId": targetUserId //Looks for a doc with the userId of the player
        }, { $set: updateObject }, //Uses the $set Mongo modifier to set value at a path
        false, //Create the document if it does not exist (upsert)
        true //This query will only affect a single object (multi)
    );
}
```

It works fine if I do a command like

```
setPlayerDataField("KingSlizzard",{"credits": 20});
```

It would result in the document like this

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "59a8668f900bea0528b63fdc"
  },
  "userId": "KingSlizzard",
  "credits": 20,
  "settings": {
    "music": 1,
    "sfx": 0
  }
}
```

The value for credits is now 20 yay! This is desired.

However, if I do this command...

```
setPlayerDataField("KingSlizzard",{"settings": {"music":0}});
```

It would result in the document like this

```
{
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "59a8668f900bea0528b63fdc"
      },
      "userId": "KingSlizzard",
      "credits": 20,
      "settings": {
        "music": 0
      }
    }
```

All I wanted to do was set only the settings/music value to 0. This result is NOT desired since we lost the sfx value.

So my question is, how do I update a value in a sub object without replacing the whole sub object itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a specific property of a child document, use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/document/#document-dot-notation). In your example, write it as:

```
setPlayerDataField("KingSlizzard", {"settings.music": 0});
```

See the [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents) in the MongoDB docs.

> To specify a <field> in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation.

Comment: Thank you! For future reference, dot notation also works when executing bulk queries with `bulkWrite`